# Check if async function has a random loop is finished

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, async-await, request

I'm working on a simple task which will get some data from a website and check it in another website so i get the data successfully and created a loop to check every value of the data but the problem is because of nodejs sending all the requests and then get the response it's done some terrible with me

1. The index is not arranged at the right way which means when I'm checking the `i` value in the console sometimes became 55 then 2 then 26 then 5 - so i can't check if the loop is finished by the index
2. The checking condition became random so cannot catch if it's finished and push all the results inside the array or not

What is happening is that it's returning the result of the array every time the condition is true but I don't want this I want to get all the results inside the array after finish checking everything - and i tried to check for the array result out of the loop but it's get me 4 or 5 just from the data and sometimes give me nothing because all the requests is sent and the loop is finished and I'm waiting for the response so I can't catch the right way to check if all the responses is received

Here's my code:

```
const http = require("http");
const r = require("request");
const $ = require("jquery-jsdom");
var arr = [];
let data_list_req = function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        r({
            //get the data from this url
            url: "https://example.com/",
            method: "GET"
        }, function(err,resp,htm) {
            resolve(htm)
        })
    })
}
data_list_req().then((response) => {
    let tr =  $($($(response).find("table")[0]).html()).find("tr");
    let data1_list =  tr.find("td:nth-child(2)");
    var data2_list =  tr.find("td:nth-child(1)");
    for(let i = 0, q = 0; i < data2_list.length, q < data1_list.length; i++, q++) {
         if (data1_list[q].innerHTML == "text") {
            //second step get the data code
            let result_page =  "http://example.com/code.php";
            let check =  function() {
                return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
                    r({
                        url: result_page,
                        method: "POST",
                        formData: {
                            "list": data2_list[i].innerHTML+":text"
                        }
                    },  function(err,resp,htm) {
                        resolve(htm)
                    })
                })
            }
            check().then((resp) => {
                let proxy_check =  function() {
                    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
                        var code =  $($(resp).find("table").html()).find("tr")[1].getAttribute("code");
                         console.log(code);
                         console.log(data2_list[i].innerHTML+":text")
                         //last step checking the data
                        r({
                            url:  "http://example.com/checkdata.php?data="+data2_list[i].innerHTML+":"+data1_list[q].innerHTML+"&code="+code,
                            method: "GET"
                        },  function(err,resp,htm) {
                             resolve(htm);
                        })
                    })
                }
                proxy_check().then( (checked) => {
                    //data
                    let first_data =  $(checked).find("td")["prevObject"][1].innerHTML;
                    let second_data =  $(checked).find("td")["prevObject"][2].innerHTML;
                    let check_status =  $(checked).find("td")["prevObject"][3].innerHTML;
                     console.log(first_data+":"+second_data)
                     console.log(check_status)
                    if (check_status == "working") {
                        arr.push(first_data+":"+second_data)
                        console.log(arr)
                    }
                })
            })  
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was posted this question from a long time ago and tried many things and they didn't work but at the end i created a recursion function which will be loop through the array one by one and wait for response and then after finished all the requests and receive all responses it's will return the last result as argument and execute my function

My actual problem was in 2 points

1. All the requests is sending randomly and also the responses are returned randomly
2. When I'm looping through the array's I'm done a condition which will filter the ports and get just proxies with 8080 and that causes a new problem

Here's a an example of how the function works

```
const r = require("request");
const jsdom = require("jsdom")
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

//use Promise to allow the response to be accessed anywhere not just inside request module function
function httpRequest(url, method) {
  return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
      r({
        url: url,
        method: method,
      }, function(err, resp, data) {
        resolve(data)
      }) 
  })
}
/*
    @param 1 > holds the object who we will loop through
    @param 2 > holds function who will be executed after the loop is finished and presend the result after scraping through all of the object keys as argument to execute your function after scraping the object
    @param 3, param 4 > they shouldn't get any value they are uses for the recursion operation so the only required is just the first, second parameter
*/
function loop(el, fn, val = [], n = 0) {
  //access object keys as array
  var elKeys = Object.keys(el);
  var valKeys = Object.keys(val);
  //get the key and url of the function
  var url = el[elKeys[n]], k = elKeys[n];

  //codition to stop the function and execute fn param after finishing the loop
  if (elKeys.length !== valKeys.length) {
    httpRequest(url, "GET").then(data => {
      //parse the results as dom object to access elements
      var doc = new JSDOM(data)
      //access title tag
      var title = doc.window.document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML
      console.log(title)

      //add elements for val array for comparison operation
      val.push(title)
      //increment {n} variable to navigate into the next index when re use the function
      n++;
      //recursion function
      loop(el, fn, val, n)
    })
  } else {
    //after finished pass the result as argument and execute my function
    fn(val)
  }
}


var obj = {
    "url 1": "https://example.com/",
    "url 2": "https://www.google.com/",
    "url 3": "https://www.youtube.com/"
}
loop(obj, function(results) {
    console.log(results, "finished")
})
```

I hope that's helpful for someone

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a variable `requests` which maintains a count of promises which a code has submitted to the event loop and you need to decrement the count of `requests` once the promise resolves. Once the count becomes zero you can resolve the promise.

For example -

```
const http = require("http");
const r = require("request");
const $ = require("jquery-jsdom");
var arr = [];
let requests = 0;
let data_list_req = function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        r({
            //get the data from this url
            url: "https://example.com/",
            method: "GET"
        }, function(err,resp,htm) {
            resolve(htm)
        })
    })
}
const data = await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    data_list_req().then((response) => {
        let tr =  $($($(response).find("table")[0]).html()).find("tr");
        let data1_list =  tr.find("td:nth-child(2)");
        var data2_list =  tr.find("td:nth-child(1)");
        for(let i = 0, q = 0; i < data2_list.length, q < data1_list.length; i++, q++) {
         if (data1_list[q].innerHTML == "text") {
            //second step get the data code
            requests++;
            let result_page =  "http://example.com/code.php";
            let check =  function() {
                return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
                    r({
                        url: result_page,
                        method: "POST",
                        formData: {
                            "list": data2_list[i].innerHTML+":text"
                        }
                    },  function(err,resp,htm) {
                        resolve(htm)
                    })
                })
            }
            check().then((resp) => {
                let proxy_check =  function() {
                    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
                        var code =  $($(resp).find("table").html()).find("tr")[1].getAttribute("code");
                         console.log(code);
                         console.log(data2_list[i].innerHTML+":text")
                         //last step checking the data
                        r({
                            url:  "http://example.com/checkdata.php?data="+data2_list[i].innerHTML+":"+data1_list[q].innerHTML+"&code="+code,
                            method: "GET"
                        },  function(err,resp,htm) {
                             resolve(htm);
                        })
                    })
                }
                proxy_check().then( (checked) => {
                    //data
                requests--;
                    let first_data =  $(checked).find("td")["prevObject"][1].innerHTML;
                    let second_data =  $(checked).find("td")["prevObject"][2].innerHTML;
                    let check_status =  $(checked).find("td")["prevObject"][3].innerHTML;
                     console.log(first_data+":"+second_data)
                     console.log(check_status)
                    if (check_status == "working") {
                        arr.push(first_data+":"+second_data)
                        console.log(arr)
                    }
                    if(requests === 0){
                        resolve(arr);               
                    }
                })
            })  
        }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Simple and effective, many loaders use this exact method

Comment: it's the real code file you can install request , jquery-jsdom modules and try it 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R2NoKQVW_1XNjUMhR7b55wHnVRn6LmRF/view?usp=sharing

- if you can remove the timeout and try what you said

Comment: i tried this before but not working so i added timeout it's not the best way but it's the only way that i find it - the problem is that the loop is finished which means if i tried something after the loop - the code will be executed before pushing the data inside the array so there's no any method which will be executed after the response is received and repeated many times - it's not a loop anymore it's like a user clicking button after some of time so you can't catch how many time he will finish his clicking on the button

Comment: I just wonder are this a bug orn JavaScript or the problem with my code because also something nearly like that happens with me before when I'm using ajax i was use it to get some products from a website but when I'm click on multiple product at the same time like 4 or 5 at the same time to choose them - i found that ajax sending the requests and receive the response but the problem was with events like complete, success - it was just working for the last 1 or 2 products and deprecate the old requests because the response is just takes some more time...